# MVC3 Modelbinder EF4 ICollection property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, collections, entity-framework-4, model-binding

In an MVC3 Razor application using EF4 I have a problem.

EF4 generates POCO classes and adds navigation properties for nested collections. A navigation property is always of type `ICollection<T>`.

In a View I try to bind to a class which has such a navigation property;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[0].Quantity)
```

This would generate a correctly named input field "Model.Items[0].Quantity". But because the property is `ICollection<T>`, I cannot use indexers. So I try:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items.First().Quantity)
```

But that will generate an incorrect input field with the id "Quantity", and the DefaultModelBinder will not be able to bind correctly.

So, how can I bind a Model with a nested ICollection property?